# Which is the most used name?

Tags: ruby

I am working on a ruby on rails site and I want to check its database for which is the most frequent name among the registered users.

There is a row called "First Name" for which I will go through. I don't mind about case sensitive right now.

Any convenient way to for example check what is the most popular name and then the second most popular, the third most popular and so on?

What I thought of is to get all users in an array and then do @users.each do |user|, then record the names in an array and after that to count the duplicates of each record that has more than one element recorded. I am not sure if its the proper way though.

Comment: Better prepare a query in SQL thus sparing all the spurios selects and in code checks.

Comment: If you have an array with all the First Names you can simply use a hash to count it.

For example
`fnames = ["Apple", "Ben, "Ben", "John"]`
`counts = Hash.new(0)`
`fnames.each{ |name| counts[name] += 1 }`
Will output
# => {"Apple" => 1, "Ben" => 2, "John" => 1}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can do it using `ActiveRecord`:

```
User.group(:first_name).order('popularity desc').pluck(:first_name, 'count(*) as popularity')
```

This code translates to the SQL:

```sql
SELECT "users.first_name", count(*) as popularity FROM "users"
GROUP BY first_name
ORDER BY popularity
```

and you get something like:

```
[["John", 2345], ["James", 1986], ["Sam", 1835], ...]
```

If you want only the top ten names, you can limit the number of results simply by adding `limit`:

```
User.group(:first_name).order('popularity desc').limit(10).pluck(:first_name, 'count(*) as popularity')
```

Another option is to use the [`count`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count) API:

```
User.group(:first_name).count
=> {"Sam" => 1835, "Stefanos" => 2, ...}

# ordered
User.group(:first_name).order('count_all desc').count
=> {"John" => 2345, "James" => 1986, "Sam" => 1835, ...}

# top 3
User.group(:first_name).order('count_all desc').limit(3).count
=> {"John" => 2345, "James" => 1986, "Sam" => 1835 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following SQL statement

```
select count(*) as count from users group by users.first_name order by count desc
```

Will return you the top most results. As Boris said, using just sql is the right way to go here.

Otherwise if you want to load all the users, you could do so by map-reduce.

```
@users.group_by(&:first_name).sort(&:count).reverse
```

Will give you an array of users sorted descending by their names.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `ActiveRecord`:

```
User.group(:first_name).count
```

Generated SQL is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, name AS name FROM `users` GROUP BY name
```

Will output a hash of { name => number_of_occurances } e.g

`{"John" => 29, "Peter" => 87, "Sarah" => 2}`

Comment: I get `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'first_name'`

Comment: tested at rails 4.1 ruby 2.0! should work on previous version too i guess

Comment: shouldn't it be `User.group(:first_name).count`?

Comment: yes you are right! i noticed a warning with my way (though it worked) .. updating my answer .. thanks